# How to determine if a device is touchscreen in Lotus Script in Registry

Tags: registry, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, touchscreen

Currently, I am using

```
var = Evaluate({@RegQueryValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE";"ControlPanel";"InputConfig")})
```

to determine if the machine is touchscreen. However, this does not return any value, which leads me to believe it either does not work, or I am calling it wrong. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your registry using regedit?

I just checked: For my "normal" Laptop this key is not available at all, thus returning an empty string is correct. If I use the exact same code to access a definitely existing variable, then it returns the value:

```vb
Dim var as Variant
var = Evaluate({@RegQueryValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER";"Console";"WindowSize")})
Messagebox var(0)
```

In addition the right return value depends on "where" you run the code. If you call an agent, then that might run on the server, and returns the registry value of the server. Same is true for any Webcode (Server Side JavaScript, e.g.): It will always return the servers value.

Comment: That shows up as empty quotations for me, too, and it is run locally

Comment: Is your client run with admin- privileges?